# Download zip file from web page where the file name is not known

Tags: vb.net

I've been looking into downloading files from a web page. Referencing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ez801hhe%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

However, the catch is, I do not know the name of the file I will be downloading.

I'm creating a VB application that runs on a schedule which will check the version of the file we have on our system with the one on the website. I've gotten this working.

The naming conventions of the file is [Description].[Version].[Zip]:
ACCESSDB.2.1.3.zip

The issue is whether the publisher of this website follows a convention of 2.1.3 to 2.1.4

It doesn't seem very robust for me to increment our version and download that.

I would like to download using a wildcard if possible, can this be achieved?

```
    Try
        Dim myStringWebResource As String = Nothing
        Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
        'myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName
        myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://website.co.uk/ACCESSMDB[Wildcard].zip", "W:\Newest.zip")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
```

Comment: The only way that could possibly work is if they set up some sort of custom routing on their side such as /Download/Latest or something. But otherwise I can't think of a way to make that work without collaboration on both sides.

Comment: That's what I feared, I'll keep thinking about a work around but it is looking grim.

Comment: Does that site have a page that lists the file? You could always scrape that first.

Comment: Have you tried asking the website owner if there's a way to find the name of the latest version?

Comment: Joel, not sure on your definition of listing the file. There is a web page which gives a download link. I made some progress of isolating the url which I'll test tomorrow. Lotus, yes I sent an email just before I left work yesterday, I hopefully will have a response tomorrow.